# Testing Framework for Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing

We actually do not use test within our application (I know that's bad and sad). I have reads a lot about Test::Unit, Shouda, minitest and the new one Bacon. But cannot make my mind yet. Basically our needs are :

- Use of watir (love it)
- Easy to learn
- Do not mess with the application (like Rspec generator - not against rspec)
- Integration with rails 3
- No clients will have to read it, only dev.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually abandoned `Test::Unit` and switched to `RSpec 2`.  Only developers have to read our tests, but RSpec seems to encourage better structured tests than `Test::Unit`.  It's different to most other testing frameworks though, so there's a small learning curve, but only for the first few days.

I also strongly advise that you don't use Rails' fixtures and you take a look at [Machinist](https://github.com/notahat/machinist).

Comment: Have to second this. Personally I find Rspec much easier to use than Test::Unit. It doesn't mess with the application that much since everything is kept contained in the `spec/` directory. Also for a popular alternative to Machinist, take a look at Factory Girl. https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails

Answer (score 2):

I would go for minitest as its the default in Ruby 1.9.2 (replacing test/unit) and use the test/unit format as it's something that a lot of developers are familiar with

Answer (score 1):

Your last bullet point leads me to recommend Test::Unit.  If you don't need the tests to be client readable, Test::Unit is much more straightforward, and doesn't require as much knowledge of the test framework before you can get started.  It looks like it integrates with Watir (although I haven't used it for that).

I'm sure you'll get lots of suggestions for each of the frameworks you listed, I'd say just pick one and start writing tests!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `Test::Unit`/`Minitest` along with the others here. You can also install `Shoulda` or use something like [this](https://gist.github.com/994621) to provide `Test::Unit` with syntax like so:

```
class TestStuff < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @foo = Klass.new
  end

  should "be of class Klass" do
    assert_equal Klass, @foo.class
  end

end
```

Have you thought of using Capybara instead of Watir?